# TCP connection not establishing for bunny on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tcp, rabbitmq, message-queue

i am trying to do simple "hello world" program with [bunny](http://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) on ruby on rails.As basic am trying to get connection with tcp its throwing an error.

```
  Could not estabilish TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:5672:
```

My code:

```
require "bunny"

begin
conn = Bunny.new
conn.start
rescue => e
     puts e
end
```

what i have to do, am completely new to this.

Comment: Do you have RabbitMQ installed? Have you confirmed it is up and running?

Comment: yes i missed that, it fix my error. thank you

Comment: Was it that you didnt have RabbitMQ installed? Or did you not have RabbitMQ server started?